# custom selectionStyle color for uitableviewcell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have been using the default colors Grey and Blue for cell selection, but I would like to try a bright orange, however I am not sure how to do custom UITableview selections.

this is the code I am using at the moment..

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
```

I have also tried

```
[cell setSelectionStyle:[UIColor orangeColor]];
```

but I get a warning saying setSelectionStyle is not an integer something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting that error because the program is expecting a `UITableViewCellSelectionStyle` where you have given it a `UIColor`. I don't know if there is way to do this programatically, but you could try and use the cell's `selectedBackgroundView` property to use your own image:

```
cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageHere.png"]] autorelease];
```

This would go in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.